# How to declare the expected exports type for a model?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, monaco-editor

I'm using `@monaco-editor/react` to set up an editor and I want monaco's typescript to validate the export types:

```
monaco.editor.createModel(
  `
  type MyType {okok:string}
  declare module './component.tsx' { export default MyType;  }
  `,
  "typescript",
  monaco.Uri.parse("file:///component.d.tsx")
);

[...]

<Editor
    language="typescript"
    theme="dark"
    path="component.tsx"
  />
```

However the declaration seems to not have any effect and monaco doesn't show an error